# HDWallet generates different addresses from same mnemonics than hardhat

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

My purpose is to get **private keys** of accounts in hardhat generated from mnemonic specified. Nevertheless, countless answers suggest it is impossible to get private keys of those accounts in hardhat.

That being said, I have a script, which accepts a mnemonic, creates an HDWallet from it and then derives other HDWallets, which should have the same addresses hardhat generates from that same mnemonic. Although they does not.

Am I missing something? Why does HDWallets generate different addresses from the same mnemonic than hardhat does?

Here is the script:

```js
async function main() {
  const mnemonic = process.env.MNEMONIC!;
  console.log('mnemonic:', mnemonic);

  const HDNode = ethers.utils.HDNode.fromMnemonic(mnemonic);

  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    const derivedNode = HDNode.derivePath(`m/44'/60'/0'/${i}`);
    console.log(`child ${i} address:`, derivedNode.address);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, I specified derive path incorrectly.

Instead of

```js
const derivedNode = HDNode.derivePath(`m/44'/60'/0'/${i}`);
```

I should have used

```js
const derivedNode = HDNode.derivePath(`m/44'/60'/0'/0/${i}`);
```